# zsh - differentiate between source ~/.zshrc and shell initially reading .zshrc

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, environment-variables, dotfiles

Is there a command or environment variable that I can test for in my `~/.zshrc` that that would differentiate between when I run `source ~/.zshrc` to update my configuration and when the shell reads `~/.zshrc` as it's initialized?

So far my solution is to set a variable at the end of the `~/.zshrc` and test for that variable on subsequent exectuion, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to directly get this information from the system or envrionment rather than hacking it together in a way that feels so fragile....

```
# somewhere in ~/.zshrc

if [[ -n $CONSOLE_ALREADY_RUNNING ]]; then
    echo "we've alredy loaded ~/.zshrc"
    echo "so you must be sourcing it"
fi

# many more lines of ~/.zshrc commands

# last line of ~/.zshrc
export CONSOLE_ALREADY_RUNNING=1
```

Seems like there should be some cleaner way to test if I'm just reloading via `source /.zshrc` or if `.zshrc` is being executed for a new instance of `zsh` that was just loaded into memory.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [How can a zsh script test whether it is being sourced?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/73008)

Comment: Searching for "zsh how do i know if a script has been sourced" would have given you the answer as the second link.

Comment: @DavidPostill, Thank you for your help. I searched for everything that I could think of, but I kept thinking "differentiate..." The references I found were only along the lines of: difference between source and . and all focused around bash even though I was searching for zsh... Anyway, you and Timotree have found the answer. Thank you so much to each of you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` is `"toplevel"` if you call the script from a shell. (for example `./script`)
`$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` is `"toplevel:file"` if you source the script. (for example `source script`)
`$ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT` is `"file"` if it's run automatically as a runtime configuration. (like `~/.zshrc` would be.)

Found the variable [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00812.html).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @timotree. I thought there must be a proper way to do this.... ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT is exactly what I was looking for, but not knowing the name I had a really difficult time finding it! My first ever Stackuser post... Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Ryan My pleasure! Credit also goes to DavidPostill for helping me find it.